# ¿Por qué da error esto?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

Siento que el título de la pregunta sea tan corto e impreciso, pero la verdad no sé qué preguntar.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal aquí?

[image]

El argumento "jugadores" es un mutableListOf() que contiene 100 jugadores con 100 puntuaciones diferentes, pero por alguna extraña razón, a Kotlin no le gusta el código y me tira un error. Si soluciono este error haciendo lo que el IDE me pide, me elimina el tipo de dato que devuelve, es decir, el MutableList, pero si lo hago, me salta otro error aquí precisamente y si lo soluciono, revierte los cambios.

Es como el juego del gato y el ratón, pero no logro entender qué está mal aquí.

Comment: no soy de java, pero me chirrian esas llaves ahi, ¿No sería `.sortBy(x -> x.puntuacion)`?? y el error dice explicitamente: *Elimina el retono explicito de tipo de cierre en la funcion mostrarResultado*

Comment: @NicolasOñate Nada. Independientemente de eso, sigue fallando. He puesto:     return jugadores.sortBy { it.puntuacion } y sigue dando el mismo fallo. La cosa es el tipo de retorno, el " : MutableList<Jugador>"

Comment: y si no usas llaves y usas parentesis?

Comment: Nada, tampoco. Al final lo que he hecho es retornar un String y después convertir ese mismo String devuelto a mutableList.

Comment: agradesco la imagen pero tambien agradeceria el codigo en formato texto.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad, no puede declarar explícitamente el tipo de retorno en un Kotlin lambda:

> One thing missing from the lambda expression syntax presented above is
> the ability to specify the return type of the function.

Español:

> Una cosa que falta en la sintaxis de la expresión lambda presentada
> anteriormente es la capacidad de especificar el tipo de retorno de la
> función.

Documentacion: [Liga](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions) 
Sitio en ingles: [Liga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56311548/17161735)

***En cuanto al codigo***

Personalmente sugeriria pasar a una funcion anonima con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
fun(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
    return x + y
}
```

ó

```
fun(jugadores: MutableList): MutableList {
    //contenido
}
```

como veras la expresion lambda desaparece y la funciona anonima carece de nombre.

Comment: alguna sugerencia sobre el código en la pregunta de acuerdo a esta aclaración?

Comment: @Alfabravo a ver si la he resuelto bien tengo rato que no veo Kotlin XD

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que en este caso, no es necesario especificar el tipo retorno y el problema principal es el valor que tratas de obtener como retorno de tu función, en lugar de definir la propiedad como texto en `.sortBy{...}` usa `.sortBy{it.puntuacion}`

```
//fun mostrarResultado(jugadores : MutableList<Jugador>) {
fun mostrarResultado(jugadores : MutableList<Jugador>) {
    //return jugadores.sortBy{"puntuacion"}
    return jugadores.sortBy{it.puntuacion}
}
```